# WCF service error no endpoint listening on HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm trying to consume a WCF data service from another application, both are running locally on my machine. I am able to consume it from the console and visit the WCF endpoint from the browser. However, my application cannot reach the application for some reason. Both applications are running on HTTPS. Any ideas?

(Error while consuming the endpoint from the asp.net application)
[image: Service trying to access endpoint]

(Consuming successfully endpoint from console with svcutil)
[image: Confirmed from console that the endpoint exists]

Comment: first screen error is 404 error. It means that web server is alive and is listening for incoming connections. However you should check the URL path. Do you have WCF server application the same for both (woring and non-working) cases ? Can you try the [Add service reference](http://dotnetlearners.com/wcf/consuming-wcf-service-in-asp-net-application) from VS is it wokring?

Comment: @oleksa yes, adding the service discovers it successfully. i modified the reference to use the https url, but for some reason i still get the issue. i wonder if i have to a self-signing certificate to MMC to get this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i had to add `<security mode="Transport" />` to the my `basicHttpBinding` tag in the service's web config.

[image: service's web config]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the log details ,if you don't find anything new, try the following steps to check:

1. Check for spelling and other similar errors.
2. Check your network Settings.
3. Try using IIS to host services.